# Emacs Misaligned Line Numbers with display-line-numbers-mode

Tags: emacs, line-numbers

I just migrated from Linux to Mac. I'm using the setting `display-line-numbers-type 'visual`. On Linux, my line numbers were aligned fine, but on Mac they are misaligned as seen in
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpY3m.png) (using the same config).

Note, the `display-line-numbers-width` setting doesn't fix this, increasing it just shifts the misalignment to the right.

The only other relevant configuration I'm using is `global-display-line-numbers-mode`.

Comment: Are you using the same font on both systems?.. (The docs have an explicit note on needing a monospace font.)

Comment: I'm not but using a monospace font fixed it, thanks!